# Iframe form results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I want to do the following.

I have a form that I will submit to my booking engine and want to display results either in new page if possible or using a Div, like basically if the user clicks the submit button it shows a Iframe or a different page.

I'm a total newbie in this.

Comment: Might be worth googling it first to see how far you get

Comment: That's what forms do by default, don't they?

Comment: Forms submit, but to ´_self´- that is the active window. Add a `target`-attribute to the form-tag should do what you want (see answer)

Answer (score 1):

In your `form`-tag, try adding a `target` attribute:

- `_blank` for a new window
- Name of frame for frame submission

Such as:

```
<form method="post" action="bookUrl" target="_blank">...</form>
```

Or

```
<iframe name="formFrame"></iframe>
<form method="post" action="bookUrl" target="formFrame">...</form>
```

Comment: yes, but target attr is available since html5

Comment: Hmm. I thought I'd used this since late 90s when frames where the thing...

Comment: Ok how do I hide the iframe and only display it when you click on submit button?

Comment: @mariusnn you mean target (for form tag!) available since 90s ?

Comment: @kirugan Yes, from what I remember I have done form-submission to different frames (similar use as target of an a-tag).